# pdf.savefig gives "An error opening...This file is already open...corrupted" when saving Pie chart to PDF

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot pie graphs using my a CSV file I have created via webscrapping.
I am able to print/show the pie graphs but unable to save it on PDF file. I tried removing plt.show()/adding it back after pdf.savefig(fig) but that did not work. Here is my Code:

(Part of the CSV file is below the Python code)

```
from cmath import inf
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer
import pandas as pd
#%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(palette="Paired")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf

data_frame = pd.read_csv("UFCstats.csv")

data_frame.head(500)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["totalwins","totalloss"], data=data_frame.head(500))
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages('pic.pdf')

for ind in df.index:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    fig.set_size_inches(5,5)
    df.iloc[ind].plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, shadow=True, title=data_frame.iloc[ind]["Fullname"], explode=[0.03,0.03], autopct='%1.1f%%')
    ax.set_ylabel("total wins are " + str(data_frame.iloc[ind]["totalwins"]))
    ax.set_xlabel("total losses are " + str(data_frame.iloc[ind]["totalloss"]))
    pdf.savefig(fig)
plt.show()
```

[image: UFCstats]

Error when trying to open the PDF file: "There was an error opening this document. This file is already open or in use by another application"

Comment: Thank you so much! please put your answer onto Solution area so I can give you credit. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to close the pdf file at the end of the code (outside the for loop). This will close the file and you can open it without issues. Use `pdf.close()` to close the file.